# Is there a possibility to insert multiple hyperlinks to into the same field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, column, hyperlink, custom-field-types

Is there an option on SharePoint / Info path to choose to create a field that will enable to insert multiple hyperlinks on the same field instead of creating another field for that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **No**, The multiple entries only introduced by `Choice field` and `Lookup field` that **didn't** support linkable items.

---

**The workaround**

Creating `Multiple lines of text` field with **Enhanced rich text** (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks) that provide you adding `hyperlinks`

[image]

**Output**

[image]